# How can I wait browser to close till server call gets complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, browser

I'm trying to call one service which updates data on browser close or tab close. The problem is that service call using `$http` and its async so according to me browser unload event cancels that call and close the browser. I want browser to wait until I get response/error for that service call.

I tried calling `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` but its not working.

```
function releaseDocument(e) {
    EventService.releaseDocument().then(function() {
        window.close();
    }, function() {
        window.close();
    });
}

$window.onbeforeunload = releaseDocument;
$window.onunload = releaseDocument;
```

Can anyone help or suggest any alternatives to achieve the same!?

Comment: If you wait until tab closes it's too late in my way of thinking. Consider a browser crash or power failure... event won't get triggered, or user has no connection at that time. Best to send it earlier where you have a chance to catch failed request

Comment: It's just not doable.

Comment: @charlietfl I agree with you. Its fine for that kind of situation. For now just want to handle browser close manually.

Answer (score 0):

**May be we can do it by using synchronous AJAX call, and also It's my suggestion only.**

---

> We will show a confirmation box when you close browser/tab. at this same time we will call your service **synchronously**. But we should call this service before execute the confirm box line. So sync call will execute every line and return the result then only the confirmation will fire/ or close the tab. Si here we have few time to execute the function.

---

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Do you want close this browser";    
   releaseDocument()// it should be an sync function ( like you can set async:false in your ajax options 

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

Comment: That's why I told it's my suggestion only. I didn't test it . :(